# I want two entries for same share in google portfolio

Tags: portfolio

I want to add (and edit occasionally) two separate entries for the same share (with same symbol) in my google portfolio. That is, I want to have ISA and non-ISA holdings of same shares in one portfolio.
How do I do this ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mean the same security, not the same share, right?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is probably to split them across different portfolios. Under the "edit portfolio" section there is a "new portfolio" link that allows you to create further portfolios. This will also separate things like P&L so is probably ideal.

Comment: No. That is what I do now and I have to switch back and forth.  What I need is the ability (using a tag say) to put the same symbol in the Edit Portfolio list more than once.  For example,  MRCH   BNKR  BNKR*  CTY  CTY*  WTAN